# MySQL 'AND' gives me error

Tags: php, mysql, select

I have this MySQL query:

```
$querynotis = "SELECT * FROM notifications WHERE pid = " . $_SESSION['sess_id'] . " AND read = 0";
```

And it gives me the error;

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'read = 0' at line 1

If I remove the:

```
AND read = 0
```

part, it works perfectly fine. What could I have done wrong?

Comment: Print the value of `$querynotis` before trying to execute the query; you'll probably notice something.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Syntax error due to using a reserved word as a table or column name in MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23446377/syntax-error-due-to-using-a-reserved-word-as-a-table-or-column-name-in-mysql)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`READ` is a Reserved Keyword and happens to be the name of your column. In order to avoid syntax error, the column name should be escaped using backticks. Ex,

```
$pid = $_SESSION['sess_id'];
$querynotis = "SELECT * FROM notifications WHERE pid = $pid AND `read` = 0";
```

- [MySQL Reserved Keywords List](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html)

Another way, rather than escaping it with backtick:

```
$pid = $_SESSION['sess_id'];
$querynotis = "SELECT * FROM notifications n WHERE pid = $pid AND n.read = 0";
```

If you have the privilege to alter the table, change the column name that is not on the *Reserved Keyword List* to prevent the same error from getting back again on the future.

---

As a sidenote, the query is vulnerable with [`SQL Injection`](http://bobby-tables.com/) if the value(*s*)  of the variables came from the outside. Please take a look at the article below to learn how to prevent from it. By using `PreparedStatements` you can get rid of using single quotes around values.

- [How to *prevent SQL injection* in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: Thank you, didn't know that. I'll edit the column-name right away. The variables does not come from the outside so I'll not be having troubles with SQL injections. Thanks for the heads up though.

Answer (score 0):

use this query, you are trying to use reserved keyword of mysql. READ is a reserve keyword. Use backtick operator

```
$querynotis = "SELECT * FROM notifications WHERE pid = " . $_SESSION['sess_id'] . " AND `read` = '0'";
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! Helped me much :)